# How to configure WebScarab to intercept only POST requests?

Tags: proxy, tools, tampering

I'm trying to make WebScarab intercept only POST requests. On the Intercept tab below Methods I've selected only POST, but it still intercepts all GET and POST requests, so it's quite hard to tamper data, because of massive amount of traffic going on. How can I configure WebScarab so that it will intercept only POST requests?

Comment: Finally works after unchecking Intercept responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to unckeck *Intercept responses*.

Comment: @JensErat: The OP is answering is own question here to allow anyone else encountering the same issue to quickly find the solution. He was not thanking himself ;) !

Comment: Indeed. This answer pretty well matched the "thank you" pattern, seems I was a little too fast this time.